# ¿Cómo podría agregar el atributo "selected" a una option al cargar mi pagina?

Tags: javascript, html

Este es un pequeño ejemplo, en el input tipo hidden coloco el valor de una consulta mysqli en este ejemplo sería rojo, entonces en mi select existe la option rojo, quiero que al cargar la pagina, haga una comparación del valor del input con lo que hay en el select si hay una coincidencia entonces que la opcion quede con el atributo selected, si me podrían dar una orientación en javascript puro sería de mucha ayuda, ya lo intente con la funcion selectedOption() pero no logro que me funcione.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Pagina web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="funcionesjs/funciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="selectedOption()">

<form action="seleccionar_option.php" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" id="oculto" name="oculto" value="rojo">

    <select name="colores" id="colores">
        <option value="verde">Verde</option>
        <option value="amarillo">Amarillo</option>
        <option value="azul">Azul</option>
        <option value="rojo">Rojo</option>
    </select> 



</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Debes agregar el codigo donde defines 'selectedOption()'

Comment: al parecer ya lo solucione un pequeño document.getElementById('colores').value = oculto;
oculto que es mi valor del input y al cargar la pagina me deja en rojo sin agregarle selected

Comment: la asignación debería ser `document.getElementById('colores').selectedIndex = oculto;`

Comment: ¿Que sentido tiene hacer una funcion y un hidden si ya se sabe el valor de antemano? ¿No sería mas logico poner el atributo directamente?

Comment: @JDev Porque mi pagina dónde requiero esto es de editar un usuario, entonces quiero que el usuario vea directamente su información que esta en la BD, se me ocurria hacer un switch de PHP pero tendría que hacer un caso para cada opción, ya que en el select podrá seleccionar la información que desea cambiar, la otra opción era poner el valor en un input tipo text pero no quiero que el usuario meta información que no es, pero bueno tal vez le di vueltas innecesarias apenas voy empezando y me funciona bien o hace lo que quiero, gracias por comentar, buen día. :)

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código php que genera esa página? creo que te estas liando y es bueno tener una buena base para no arrastrar hábitos que dificulten el aprendizaje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta sería la solución, lo intente con selectedIdex como dice @Fly pero no me funciona.

```js
function selectedOption(){


 var oculto = document.getElementById("oculto").value;


document.getElementById('colores').value = oculto;

}
```